# Запятая перед союзом "и"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и":
"Основная часть средств расходуется не на образовательный процесс, а на инфраструктуру, оздоровление обучающихся(,) и в меньшей степени - на их обучение".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед союзом **И** запятая не нужна, потому что он соединяет однородные дополнения. А вот словосочетание **в меньшей степени**, содержащее оценку меры того, о чем говорится, я бы выделила как вводное: *"Основная часть средств расходуется не на образовательный процесс, а на инфраструктуру, оздоровление обучающихся и - в меньшей степени - на их обучение"*.